# Post request 1000 item limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kotlin

I've been working on a mini webapp in kotlin using ktor (to play conway's game of life). I've run into an issue where not all the data I send from the front end in a jquery post request makes it to the server. I construct a javascript object with 4500 keys on the front end and post it, but the server only receives an object with 1000 keys present. Doing some googling led me to some resources regarding php issues but nothing regarding straight javascript. I'm using jquery 3.3.1. Here is the client side code making the post:

```
    let m = buildBoard();
    // this logs 4500
    console.log("size of posted object: " + Object.keys(m).length);
    $.post("/update", m, (responseJson) => {
        responseJson = JSON.parse(responseJson);
        // this logs 1000, even though it should be the same size as what we posted
        console.log("size of response: " + Object.keys(responseJson).length);
        for(const key of Object.keys(responseJson)) {
            let arr = JSON.parse(key);
            drawCell(parseInt(arr[0]), parseInt(arr[1]), responseJson[key]);
        }
    });
```

The server basically takes the json object its sent (representing a board state) and transforms it before sending the updated board back to the client. Logging on the server tells me the server is only receiving 1000 squares of the board which leads me to believe that the problem is on the js end (but I'm happy to post the server code if anyone thinks that could be the issue).

Comment: I would investigate the limit of your server's json parser. These parsers have a limit by default to prevent attacks with large amount of data

Comment: Try using wireshark or a proxy, and check if the data is actually being sent, should reduce the issue

Comment: Which server are you using on the server-side? Tomcat, Jetty, VertX, SpringBoot, RatPack, ... ? What happens to the other 3500 posts, do they time-out, give error 500, ... ? Most browsers can only handle 17 concurrent posts at a time

Comment: I'm using netty as my server Jan. I'm also not making 4500 posts but one post of an object with 4500 keys so I don't think the concurrent post thing is an issue. I'm using GSON to parse the json data on the server end and the documentation doesn't mention any limit so I don't think that's what's going on. I'll use wireshark and see what's going on next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I couldn't figure out why the limit existed so I just switched to posting the stringified object and parsing it back into JSON on the server, which resulted in all the data making it to the server.